# GitHub: What is the difference between Template and Fork concepts and when to use?

Tags: templates, github, git-fork

I was wondering how GitHub templates differentiates from forks and why should I use them instead of forking a repository?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I understood, you can't pull updates from templates the same way you can pull them from forks.
You are unable to push changes to the forked repository as well.

Templates are intended to use a repository as-is, and to use it as a boilerplate to build for example a website. It's not meant to be up-to-date with the main repository.

Edit: Also you can't fork your own repositories on GitHub; you can however use your own templates.

Comment: Actually the statement that you can't pull updates from templates is partially false. You can't do it via a `git pull && git push`. However, if the original template has a GitHub Actions to update, it is possible as the template copies would trigger an update. Here's an example: https://github.com/upptime/upptime/blob/master/.github/workflows/update-template.yml

Comment: What does this mean in terms of git?

Answer (score 7):

These are included in the official docs as well [link](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-on-github/creating-a-repository-from-a-template)

- A new fork includes the entire commit history of the parent repository, while a repository created from a template starts with a single commit.
- Commits to a fork don't appear in your contributions graph, while commits to a repository created from a template do appear in your contribution graph.
- A fork can be a temporary way to contribute code to an existing project, while creating a repository from a template starts a new project quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The same answer with [ChamaraL's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68737256/3416774) but with table

|  | Template | Fork |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Commit history | Starts with a single commit | Includes entire commit history of the parent repository |
| Do commit to it appear in your contribution graph? | Yes | No |
| Purpose | To start a new project quickly | To contribute code to an existing project temporarily |